# Change the Browser title

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I am using links to display PDF files. I wish to show the PDF in a new tab so I add target="_blank". This works fine. A new tab is opened but I wish to change the title of the tab.

The link redirects me to this controller code as follows:-

```
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
```

The pdf is displayed correctly but there is no view script so I have no control via the script. Is there a header("Browser title: ???") I can use?

TIA Effy

Comment: Browsers simply use the title tag `<title>Your name</title>`

Comment: Yes. So where do I place this? How is ZF2 rendering the file?

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, I use this trick:

I use a simple html page with an iframe like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your PDF Title</title>
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" href=""> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="/module/controller/action/param..." id="ifrm" name="ifrm" width="100%" height="100%">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The iframe contains the PDF and the page has title.
Of course, you can use javascript to have a dynamic title

Answer (score 0):

The internal pdfviewer in Firefox seems to fetch the title of the document from the metadata in the pdf.
With for instance Zend_Pdf this metadata can be manipulated.

```
$title = 'My custom title';
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($filepath);

$metadata = $pdf->getMetadata();
$metadataDOM = new DOMDocument();
$metadataDOM->loadXML($metadata);
$domTitle = $metadataDOM->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
$domTitle->nodeValue = $title;
$pdf->setMetadata($metadataDOM->saveXML());

//maybe old style document info:
$pdf->properties['Title'] = $title;//this didn't work for me


echo $pdf->render();
```

I'm no DOM manipulation expert, but this worked for me with a file created with Illustrator CS5. Freely based on the Zend Framework Documentation. You might need to do some error checking along the way.